# How to replace a line in bash

Tags: bash

How can I replace a line that starts with "string1" with "string2 lala" using Bash script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the sed utility

```
sed -e 's/^string1.*/string2 lala/'
```

<strike>or</strike>

```
sed -e 's/^string1.*/string2 lala/g'
```

to replace it every time it appears

Comment: That does not work... I need to delete all the line that contains "string1", not just replace that part

Comment: Note that the g modifier in the second version does nothing because (a) there is only one start to each line and (b) even if the caret were omitted, the first pattern with the '.*' obliterates any other 'string1' appearances on the line.

Comment: Jonathan - You are very right, about the g. It was added in the original suggestion before edits.

Answer (score 3):

using bash,

```
#!/bin/bash
file="myfile"
while read -r line
do
 case "$line" in
  string1* ) line="string2 lala"
 esac
 echo "$line"
done <"$file" > temp
mv temp $file
```

using awk

```
awk '/^string1/{$0="string2 lala"}1' file
```